# Area 51 meta link address is not up-to-date

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

If you go to the [Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), you'll see this:

> **meta.topic-name.stackexchange.com**: We don't want to talk about the site on the site itself, so each site has a meta discussion area to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags to use, etc. The meta site is also accessible through the 'meta' link at the top of each page on the main site. This is where you can help make decisions about the site itself.

Recently, these site addresses were updated to "topic-name.meta.stackexchange.com", with "meta.topic-name.stackexchange.com" changed to a redirect. The links should probably be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed as of the most recent build. Thanks for the report!